# Amp-sidebar does not close

Tags: amp-html

When the sidebar contains a nested menu, the close event does not work

```
<button on="tap:sidebar.open">Open</button>
<div className="sidebar-menu">
  <amp-sidebar id="sidebar" layout="nodisplay" class="sidebar-menu__sidebar" side="left">
    <div role="button" aria-label="close sidebar" on="tap:sidebar.toggle" tabindex="0" class="close-sidebar">✕</div>

    <amp-nested-menu layout="fill">
      <ul className="sidebar-menu__main-menu">
        <li key="item" on="tap:sidebar.close">item</li>
      </ul>
    </amp-nested-menu>
  </amp-sidebar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button on="tap:sidebar.close"
button on="tap:sidebar.toggle"
```

put something like this. let me know if it work or not.